# What objects can use the + operator?

Tags: java, operator-overloading, operators, concatenation

In Java, you can use the `+` operator on numbers such as `long, short, int and double` but also their object variants `(Long, Short, Integer and Double)` and on `Strings` for concatenation.

- On what objects is the `+ operator` also defined?
- Can I make my own objects which also use the + operator?
- Are objects that use the `+ operator` all implementations of a certain superclass? This would mean I could create a function `public static SuperClass apply(Superclass[] array)` which applies the `+ operator` iteratively on the array, so for {1,2,3} this would return 6 and for {"1","2","3"} it would return "123". Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of that other SO thread, but ok...

Comment: @sstan In my opinion the answer to that other (differently asked) question answers the present one.

Comment: @Denys: not that I'm complaining, but the other thread seems very string specific, and here OP is asking about all objects, and about the possibility of operator overloading, etc.